# How can I fix a resolution discrepancy between nested sequences?

Tags: premiere, cs5

I am very new to Premiere (CSD 5) and have put myself in a bit of a bind. I have four clips of footage I edited into one multicam clip. The clips are 720p; however, the sequence where I synced them up was 480p. I didn't notice this and so I nested that sequence inside another sequence so I could do the multicam editing.

The footage shows at the correct resolution in the multi-camera monitor, interestingly enough, but it's masked by black bars everywhere else (including when I try to export). Is there any way I can fix this without having to re-edit my entire 25 minute clip? Perhaps I could somehow make it so that all the references to the bad sequence are replaced with references to the same timestamp in a good sequence?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but I found a solution that did the trick. I opened my .prproj file with a text editor and made these find-replace all changes:

```
<MZ.Sequence.PreviewFrameSizeHeight>480
changed to
<MZ.Sequence.PreviewFrameSizeHeight>720

<MZ.Sequence.PreviewFrameSizeWidth>720
changed to
<MZ.Sequence.PreviewFrameSizeWidth>1280

<FrameRect>0,0,720,480</FrameRect>
changed to
<FrameRect>0,0,1280,720</FrameRect>
```

If anyone else has this problem and is desperate for a fix, this should do it, although I recommend making a backup first.

Comment: Welcome to Video Production.  Glad you got it worked out and thanks for posting how you got it.